# Trouble uploading project to GitHub pages?

Tags: github-pages

I have my project working on localhost perfectly, but when I deploy my app and I go to the GitHub Pages, it is just blank with an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

How to avoid that error message?

Comment: Check and make sure your url links are in order...

Comment: I think this may have to do with my base href? Does that need to be changed from "/" (root) when deploying?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [type of GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites), and verify your GitHub repository is one of them:

- To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named **`<user>.github.io`**.
- To publish an organization site, you must create a repository owned by an organization that's named **`<organization>.github.io`**.

> Unless you're using a custom domain, user and organization sites are available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io`.
>
> - The source files for a project site are stored in the same repository as their project.
>     Unless you're using a custom domain, project sites are available at `http(s)://<user>.github.io/<repository>` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io/<repository>`.

Then check the [source of publication](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites):

> - The default publishing source for user and organization sites is the `master` branch.
>     If the repository for your user or organization site has a `master` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch.
>     You cannot choose a different publishing source for user or organization sites.
>
> The default publishing source for a project site is the `gh-pages` branch.
>   If the repository for your project site has a `gh-pages` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch.
>   Project sites can also be published from the master branch or a `/docs` folder on the `master` branch